# SwipeRefreshLayout does not work anymore, if I change activity, and then come back

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, refresh, swipe, swiperefreshlayout

This is my xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
   android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
   android:layout_below="@id/id_bar"
   android:layout_marginBottom="0.5dp"
   android:background="@color/blue"        
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/list"
           android:dividerHeight="0dp"
           android:layout_gravity="top"
           android:divider="@null"
           android:background="@color/yellow"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           />

       <com.bartoszlipinski.recyclerviewheader2.RecyclerViewHeader
           android:id="@+id/header"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="70dp"
           android:visibility="gone"
           android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top">

           <include
               android:id="@+id/header_profile"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:background="@drawable/rounded_top_green"
               layout="@layout/header_profile"/>
       </com.bartoszlipinski.recyclerviewheader2.RecyclerViewHeader>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/placeholderContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/placeholderPic"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/pin_newtrips"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/placeholderText"
                android:layout_below="@id/placeholderPic"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textSize="28dp"
                android:textColor="@color/gray32"
                android:text="@string/home.status.heading.setup"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/placeholderAddItems"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/placeholderText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></RelativeLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I initiate it via butterknife:

```
@InjectView(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout) SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
```

This is my refreshListener:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // Refresh items
        if(timeLineAdapter!= null)
            timeLineAdapter.setLastAnimatedPosition(0);
            refresh(false);
    }
});
```

I call this on onResume, so that it will work if I come back to it.
Now initially it works, if I press home button and come back, it works.
If I change my activity to another one, and then come back to it, it doesn't work anymore. How can this be fixed?

EDIT: As you can see, the main child of the SwipeRefreshLayout is a FrameLayout which contains the RecyclerView, my RecyclerViewHeader and a placeholder for the list (in here, cause swiping down on the placeholder should also swipe to refresh.
I Added between this 2 views, a ScrollView, and now the swipe to refresh works. BUT, having the recyclerview inside the scrollview ruins my recyclerView. I can scroll down but not up. Any other ideeas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had timelineList.setVisibility(View.Invisible) inside the code when I would check to see if I have objects to show inside the list. 
I removed that and set this instead:

```
       if(timeLineAdapter != null) {
        timeLineAdapter.clearItems();
        timeLineAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Now the list is not set as invisible nowhere.
I added my placeholder and list inside the SwipeRefreshLayout, thinking that it will work on both, but in reality it only works on the list, so if the list is gone, the pull to refresh is gone